# Pymongo cannot connect to remote database when in virtual environment

Tags: python, mongodb, virtualenv, pymongo

So I am trying to connect to remote MongoDB database using pymongo but it fails to connect when the script is run in virtual environment. It can connect to local db in venv, as well as it connects when its not run inside virtual enviroment. I wonder why it fails only in virutalenv. Both globally and on venv im using pymongo version 3.6.0.

My code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient 
from config import *

mongo=os.environ["mongodb"]
try: 
    #local test
    #conn = MongoClient()
    #production
    conn = MongoClient(mongo)

    print("Connected successfully!!!") 
except:   
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB")
```

Comment: Remove the try / except to see the real error message.

Comment: You should avoid catching naked exceptions in any codebase, it just masks issues. A good blog post: http://www.wilfred.me.uk/blog/2013/11/03/no-naked-excepts/

Comment: Thanks, good source, it helped.